# Pose direction not correct on rViz

Tags: ros, pose, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to work on a complete coverage problem of a static map.

So, just to begin, I assumed my map to have no obstacles.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <vector>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Point.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PointStamped.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Pose.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseArray.h>
#include <nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid.h>
#include <nav_msgs/GetMap.h>
#include <ros/console.h>
#include <ros/console.h>

int rows = 1000, columns = 1000;
std::vector<int> path;
int robot_radius = 5; // Assume circle for now 
int source_r = 100, source_c = 100; // Coordinates of the center of the circle
int current_r = source_r, current_c = source_c; // Current position of center
int dir = 1; // +ve for moving right
int map_2d[1000][1000];
ros::Publisher pub;
geometry_msgs::PoseArray pa;
geometry_msgs::Point p1;
geometry_msgs::Point p2;
geometry_msgs::Point p3;
geometry_msgs::PointStamped p01;
geometry_msgs::PointStamped p02;
geometry_msgs::PointStamped p03;

int index(int r, int c)
{
    return (r * 1000) + c;
}

void make_map(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid& map)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
            map_2d[i][j] = map.data[index(i, j)];
}
bool free_left()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
            if(map_2d[i][j] == 0)
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void cover(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid& map)
{
    p1.x = source_r;
    p1.y = source_c;
    p1.z = 0; int count = 0;
    while(free_left())
    {
        if(dir == 1)
        {
            if(count == 1)
            {
                p3.x = current_r;
                p3.y = current_c;
                p3.z = 0;
            }
            count++;
            if(current_c + robot_radius < columns)
            {
                path.push_back(index(current_r, current_c));
                geometry_msgs::Pose p;
                p.position.x = current_r;
                p.position.y= current_c;
                p.position.z = 0;
                p.orientation.x = 0;
                pa.poses.push_back(p);
                map_2d[current_r][current_c] = 100;
                ROS_INFO("%i", path.back());
                // mark the cells as visited
                for(int i = -5; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    for(int j = -5; j < 5; j++)
                    {
                        map_2d[current_r+i][current_c+i] = 100;
                    }
                }
                // Increment position
                current_c += 2*robot_radius;
            }
            else
            {
                dir = -1; // Move in the left direction
                current_r += 2*robot_radius;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(current_c + robot_radius > 0)
            {
                path.push_back(index(current_r, current_c));
                geometry_msgs::Pose p;
                p.position.x = current_r;
                p.position.y= current_c;
                p.position.z = 0;
                p.orientation.x = 180;
                pa.poses.push_back(p);
                map_2d[current_r][current_c] = 100;
                ROS_INFO("%i", path.back());
                // mark the cells as visited
                for(int i = -5; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    for(int j = -5; j < 5; j++)
                    {
                        //visited[index(current_r + i, current_c + i)] = 100;
                        map_2d[current_r+i][current_c+i] = 100;
                    }
                }
                // Increment position
                current_c -= 2*robot_radius;
            }
            else
            {
                dir = 1; // Move in the right direction
                current_r += 2*robot_radius;
            }
        }
        if(index(current_r, current_c) == 999990)
            break;
    }
    p2.x = current_r;
    p2.y = current_c;
    p2.z = 0;
}
            
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "planner");
    ros::NodeHandle n("~");
    ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<nav_msgs::GetMap>("/static_map");
    nav_msgs::GetMap srv;
    client.call(srv);
    nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid my_map = srv.response.map;
    pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseArray>("/poseArray", 1);
    ros::Publisher point_pub1 = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::PointStamped>("/point_1", 1);
    ros::Publisher point_pub2 = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::PointStamped>("/point_2", 1);
    ros::Publisher point_pub3 = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::PointStamped>("/point_3", 1);
    pa.header.frame_id = "map";
    p01.header.frame_id = "map";
    p02.header.frame_id = "map";
    p03.header.frame_id = "map";
    make_map(my_map);
    cover(my_map);
    p01.point = p1;
    p02.point = p2;
    p03.point = p3;
    while(ros::ok())
    {
        pub.publish(pa);
        point_pub1.publish(p01);
        point_pub2.publish(p02);
        point_pub3.publish(p03);
    }
    ros::spin();    
}
```

[image]

Purple is the first point and green is the second point in the path.

The path by my algorithm clearly moves from left to right, but the pose always points downwards(might not be clear in the picture but it does).
Does anyone know why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341833/pose-direction-not-correct-on-rviz./) by [ros-noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/50569/ros-noob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2020-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> p.orientation.x = 180;
> ```

`orientation` is a quaternion, not an RPY triplet. Assigning 180 to it does not do what it would seem you assume it does.

See the [geometry_msgs/Pose](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose.html) documentation.

You may want to read up on quaternions, the ROS wiki has some pages about them (but note they are not a ROS invention, it's generic mathematical concept): [tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ros-noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/50569/ros-noob/) on 2020-01-17**:
Thank you for your answer. I will look into it.